# Configure kern.log to give more info about a segfault

Tags: linux, logging, segmentation-fault, kernel, debian

Currently I can find in kern.log entries like this:

```
[6516247.445846] ex3.x[30901]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000400564 sp 00007fff96ecb170 error 6 in ex3.x[400000+1000]
[6516254.095173] ex3.x[30907]: segfault at 0 ip 0000000000400564 sp 00007fff0001dcf0 error 6 in ex3.x[400000+1000]
[6516662.523395] ex3.x[31524]: segfault at 7fff80000000 ip 00007f2e11e4aa79 sp 00007fff807061a0 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[7f2e11dcf000+180000]
```

(You see, apps causing segfault are named ex3.x, means exercise 3 executable).

Is there a way to ask kern.log to log the complete path? Something like:

```
[6...] /home/user/cclass/ex3.x[3...]: segfault at 0 ip 0564 sp 07f70 error 6 in ex3.x[4...]
```

So I can easily figure out from who (user/student) this ex3.x is?

Thanks!
Beco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: No, it is not possible without making code changes and recompiling the kernel.  The normal solution to this problem is to instruct your students to name their executable `<student user name>_ex3.x` so that you can easily have this information.

**However, it is possible to get the information you desire** from other methods. [Appleman1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184641/appleman1234) has provided some alternatives in his answer to this question.

**How do we know the answer is "Not possible to the the full path *in the kern.log segfault messages* without recompiling the kernel":**

We look in the kernel source code to find out how the message is produced and if there are any configuration options.

The files in question are part of the kernel source. You can download the entire kernel source as an rpm package (or other type of package) for whatever version of linux/debian you are running from a variety of places.

Specifically, the output that you are seeing is produced from whichever of the following files is for your architecture:

- [linux/arch/sparc/mm/fault_32.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/sparc/mm/fault_32.c)
- [linux/arch/sparc/mm/fault_64.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/sparc/mm/fault_64.c)
- [linux/arch/um/kernel/trap.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/um/kernel/trap.c)
- [linux/arch/x86/mm/fault.c](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c)

An example of the relevant function from one of the files(*linux/arch/x86/mm/fault.c*):

```
/*
 * Print out info about fatal segfaults, if the show_unhandled_signals
 * sysctl is set:
 */
static inline void
show_signal_msg(struct pt_regs *regs, unsigned long error_code,
        unsigned long address, struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    if (!unhandled_signal(tsk, SIGSEGV))
        return;

    if (!printk_ratelimit())
        return;

    printk("%s%s[%d]: segfault at %lx ip %p sp %p error %lx",
        task_pid_nr(tsk) > 1 ? KERN_INFO : KERN_EMERG,
        tsk->comm, task_pid_nr(tsk), address,
        (void *)regs->ip, (void *)regs->sp, error_code);

    print_vma_addr(KERN_CONT " in ", regs->ip);

    printk(KERN_CONT "\n");
}
```

From that we see that the variable passed to printout the process identifier is `tsk->comm` where `struct task_struct *tsk` and `regs->ip` where `struct pt_regs *regs`

Then from [*linux/include/linux/sched.h*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h)

```
struct task_struct {
    ...
    char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN]; /* executable name excluding path
                                 - access with [gs]et_task_comm (which lock
                                   it with task_lock())
                                 - initialized normally by setup_new_exec */
```

The comment makes it clear that the path for the executable is not stored in the structure.

For `regs->ip` where `struct pt_regs *regs`, it is defined in whichever of the following are appropriate for your architecture:

- [arch/arc/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arc/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/arm64/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm64/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/cris/include/arch-v10/arch/ptrace.h)
- [arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/cris/include/arch-v32/arch/ptrace.h)
- [arch/metag/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/metag/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/mips/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/mips/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/openrisc/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/openrisc/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/um/include/asm/ptrace-generic.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/um/include/asm/ptrace-generic.h)
- [arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h)
- [arch/xtensa/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/xtensa/include/asm/ptrace.h)

From there we see that `struct pt_regs` is defining registers for the architecture. `ip` is just:  `unsigned long ip;`

Thus, we have to look at what `print_vma_addr()` does.  It is defined in [*mm/memory.c*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/memory.c#L3676)

```
/*
 * Print the name of a VMA.
 */
void print_vma_addr(char *prefix, unsigned long ip)
{
    struct mm_struct *mm = current->mm;
    struct vm_area_struct *vma;

    /*
     * Do not print if we are in atomic
     * contexts (in exception stacks, etc.):
     */
    if (preempt_count())
        return;

    down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
    vma = find_vma(mm, ip);
    if (vma && vma->vm_file) {
        struct file *f = vma->vm_file;
        char *buf = (char *)__get_free_page(GFP_KERNEL);
        if (buf) {
            char *p;

            p = d_path(&f->f_path, buf, PAGE_SIZE);
            if (IS_ERR(p))
                p = "?";
            printk("%s%s[%lx+%lx]", prefix, kbasename(p),
                    vma->vm_start,
                    vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start);
            free_page((unsigned long)buf);
        }
    }
    up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
}
```

Which shows us that *a path* was available. We would need to check that it was *the path*, but looking a bit further in the code gives a hint that it might not matter.  We need to see what `kbasename()` did with the path that is passed to it. `kbasename()` is defined in [*include/linux/string.h*](https://web.archive.org/web/20140927171734/http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/string.h#L154) as:

```
/**
 * kbasename - return the last part of a pathname.
 *
 * @path: path to extract the filename from.
 */
static inline const char *kbasename(const char *path)
{
    const char *tail = strrchr(path, '/');
    return tail ? tail + 1 : path;
}
```

Which, even if the full path is available prior to it, chops off everything except for the last part of a pathname, leaving the filename.

Thus, no amount of runtime configuration options will permit printing out the full pathname of the file in the segment fault messages you are seeing.

---

NOTE: I've changed all of the links to kernel source to be to archives, rather than the original locations. Those links will get close to the code as it was at the time I wrote this, 2104-09. As should be no surprise, the code does evolve over time, so the code which is current when you're reading this may or may not be similar or perform in the way which is described here.

Comment: Thank you. Nice job. Your answer is no for exactly what I asked. You got the bounty, congrats. But I'll point out that @Appleman1234 was very creative to think out of my box and suggest other ways. I was tempted to accept his answer, but after reading my question, to be fair, you nailed it.

Comment: Yeah, I should have been thinking outside the box on this one. I guess the reason I didn't is that I really don't look at recompiling the kernel as a significant issue. I should have been thinking more about what is reasonable in your probable environment where recompiling and running on a custom kernel is likely a significant issue.

Comment: Funny thing, I googled this again and I ended up here. +1 for bringing me back here years later.

Comment: Tempted to update the now-dangling links to eg https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L768

Comment: @MartinDorey I've updated the kernel code links to archive.org links at *about* the time this was posted. Given that this was talking about the kernel code at a certain point in time, I don't think we can do much better than that. It's possible that there are archives which were recorded of other mirrors of the kernel at capture dates that are closer to when I actually posted this, but I'm not sure putting out the effort to find them is all that beneficial. I should have caused archives to be created of those links at the time I posted this, but, obviously, didn't think of it at the time.

Comment: I didn't double-check all of the archive links, but all of the ones which I did check at least go to something.

Answer (score 4):

That log message comes from the kernel with a fixed format that only includes the first 16 letters of the executable excluding the path as per [show_signal_msg](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/mm/fault.c#L729), see other relevant lines for segmentation fault on non x86 architectures.

As mentioned by Makyen, without significant changes to the kernel and a recompile, the message given to klogd which is passed to syslog won't have the information you are requesting.

I am not aware of any log transformation or injection functionality in syslog or klogd which would allow you to take the name of the file and run either locate or file on the filesystem in order to find the full path.

The best way to get the information you are looking for is to use crash interception software like [apport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) or [abrt](https://github.com/abrt/abrt/wiki/FAQ) or [corekeeper](https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/corekeeper). These tools store the process metadata from the /proc filesystem including the process's commandline which would include the directory run from, assuming the binary was run with a full path, and wasn't already in path.

The other more generic way would be to enable core dumps, and then to set /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern  to include [%E](http://linux.die.net/man/5/core), in order to have the core file name including the path of the binary.

Comment: As I commented in the accepted answer, you were very creative to think out of the box and gave me nice suggestions to figure out how to solve this little problem. Thank you. +1 for that. I'll probably try the "core dumps" scheme. Very clever of you.

Comment: +1 from me also. This answer provides alternate solutions for the underlying problem instead of just the expressed question. Such is often more important in real life.